# Evaluating a formula that uses summations and products of vectors

Tags: fitting, summation, vector

Could someone tell me how to find `beta1`?

I have the following data:

[image]

I don't know how to write `beta1`, and I don't find anything related on google

Please help me

#### Edit

I tried

```
beta1 = 
  (n Total[x.y] - (Total[x])(Total[y]))/(n Total[x^2] - (Total[x])^2)
```

but I got the unexpected result

```
 -6.41769 + 0.00120621 Total[5511.93]
```

Why?

Comment: `beta1 = (n*Total[x*y]-Total[x]*Total[y])/(n*Total[x^2]-Total[x]^2)` Check that carefully with several different shorter lists to try to confirm the result is correct.

Comment: @Bill it doesn't work, I tried with n=1,x={1,2},y={1,1} and it gives .23 when the real result it's 3/4

Comment: @Bill oh wait I didn't refresh the x's and y's...now it works fine :)

Comment: I checked individually and it works fine, thank you @Bill

Comment: Please note that `Dot (.)` is not the multiplication of numbers.

Comment: Please post the code text instead of screenshot of it.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ yes I've just learned that it's for matrix multiplication

Comment: @xzczd Let me look for the beta1 again, because I think I lost it. Btw I didn't know it was so easy to post the code text without write it manually..that's why I chosed a screenshot

Comment: Just use `x.y` instead of `Total[x.y]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[betahat]
betahat[x_, y_] := Module[{d = Thread[{1, x}]}, Inverse[Transpose[d].d].Transpose[d].y]
```

Example:

```
y = {4.9176, 5.0208, 4.5429, 4.5573, 5.0597, 3.8910, 5.8980, 5.6039, 
   5.8282, 5.3003, 6.2712, 5.9592, 5.0500, 8.2464, 6.6969, 7.7841, 
   9.0384, 5.9894, 7.5422, 8.7951, 6.0831, 8.3607, 8.1400, 9.1416};
x = {25.9, 29.5, 27.9, 25.9, 29.9, 29.9, 30.9, 28.9, 35.9, 31.5, 31, 
   30.9, 30, 36.9, 41.9, 40.5, 43.9, 37.5, 37.9, 44.5, 37.9, 38.9, 
   36.9, 45.8};

betahat[x, y]
```

> {-1.58437, 0.230821}

Compare to the result from `LinearModelFit`:

```
LinearModelFit[Thread[{x, y}], t, t]["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {-1.58437, 0.230821}

Comment: betahat[x,y] gives as result $\{\hat\beta_0,\hat\beta_1\}$?

Comment: @user459663, yes.

Comment: ah I see, thank you for your help kglr

Comment: I  tested the first line and it says Module needs another parameter, why?

Comment: @user459663, a cut/paste error (a comma was missing). Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
β1[x_, y_] := Module[{n = Length[x]},
                     (n x.y - Total[x] Total[y])/(n x.x - Total[x]^2)
                    ]
```